# Units of electric charge of a point compared a sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

1. Are the units of electric charge of a point and the units of electric charge a sphere the same? If not, how can we compare the magnitudes?
2. Same question, but replace charge with field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Units of electric charge are coulombs - anywhere and everywhere.

Depending on the distribution of the charge, it may be helpful to talk about surface charge density ($\frac{C}{m^2}$) or volume charge density ($\frac{C}{m^3}$), in the same way sometimes we talk about density vs. mass.

Comment: Oh I see. What about the units of the electric field of a point versus the units of an electric field of a disk?

Comment: Electric field is units of $\frac{N}{C}$ regardless of its source